# Basic authentication portected page accessible without header but not from different IP

Tags: authentication, web-application, authorization

I'm looking at a website uses basic authentication to authorise users.

When I look at the request, once authenticated, it appends the header `Authorization: Basic cm9vdDpwYXNzd29yZA==` (I'm aware that this is only base64 encoded).

Now, if I remove the `Authorization` header from the request, it works fine anyways. Even if I re-run the request with `curl`, without the `Authorization` header it works fine. But if I run the same `curl` command on a different machine I get `401 Unauthorized`.

Is the basic authentication somehow paired with the IP address or something else identifying the client?

How is the authorisation accomplished in this case?

**edit:** I'm stumped. The described scenario is no longer reproducible.. Something fishy's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess one of two things is happening here:

- **The server stored your IP against your account**: This way you could login access the resource from your IP even without having to auth everytime. Not a bright idea.
- **Caching**: Your computer or ISP was caching that page (if it was the ISP - badly), and serving you that resource instead of resending the request.

Unlikely case: The server had some caching issues and was serving everyone the resource by mistake. The reason it's probably not working anymore is that - the authorization on your IP expired.

Comment: I'm guessing that this was an odd server caching issue. As this isn't reproducible, even with refreshed authentication, so I guess the server doesn't store the authentication with the IP. It can't be cached by the ISP or alike as the device is directly attached to my local interface.